# GDK : How to show status similar to 'Recording" and 'Complete"

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm developing a GDK app where I need to provide an user experience to display status text similar to video recording status that Glass provides ( displaying "Recording" status then  displaying progress indicator and finally showing 'Complete' text ). Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you'll need to write your own UI logic to do this (perhaps by using a `Dialog` with a custom layout that has the appropriate centered label and icon, with a progress bar at the bottom, and changing the label and dismissing the dialog when the action is complete).

You may want to follow [issue 271](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=271) in our issue tracker, which covers the progress indicator part of this flow.

Answer (score 0):

Tony is right. There is no way to do this naively but you can build it yourself. You can create a layout that is build exactly like the menu is built in the GDK, and then just update the setcontentview() with a new layout each time you want to move to the next card. Also you can build a layout with the holo horizontal progressbar to get the general idea but it won't be like the one Google uses.

Also wanted to add that I have built a repo that you can drop into your project for this. Here is the link: https://github.com/w9jds/GDK-ProgressBar