# How to show progress when glass menu item selected?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Common UI pattern in Glass apps is to show progress when menu item selected.

How to invoke this progress state of menu item using glass GDK?

Comment: I have created a git here:
https://github.com/w9jds/GDK-ProgressBar That you can throw into a project and use to get the same effect as in the native Google Glass applications.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible yet unless you roll your own UI logic; see my answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890241/gdk-how-to-show-status-similar-to-recording-and-complete).